# Forcing a download of a .sys file from Gmail Sent items

Tags: gmail

I emailed myself a settings file for my backup application so that if I lost my computer I would have all I need to restore files. Unfortunately this is a .sys file and was blocked by Gmail. I didn't realise this at the time but the mail was bounced and never delivered. The mail is still in the Sent items folder though.

My computer has now died and I need the configuration file to restore all the settings for my backup application but I can't download this file. The download is blocked.

Is there any way to force Gmail to let me download this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's cool is that the safety of these files isn't considered until it reaches receiving inbox. The Gmail inbox, specifically. `*.sys` is Windows, so you should have Outlook installed, right? I've read that you can download these blacklisted files when checking mail from within another email client.

There are fortunately other alternatives if you don't particularly like Outlook: [Inky](http://inky.com/) and [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) are good choices.

You should have the file in no time.